# Is there any free WiFi network available at Nyaung-U Airport (NYU)?

Tags: airports, wifi, myanmar, nyu, bagan

Is there any free WiFi network available at [Nyaung-U Airport (NYU)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyaung_U_Airport) (near Bagan, Myanmar)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of November 2019, there is no free Wi-Fi at Nyaung-U Airport (NYU).

Source: I've been there and scanned for Wi-Fi networks at a few different places in the airport:

[image]

That echoes the most recent review on [Foursquare](https://foursquare.com/v/nyaung-u-airport/4d9c6db25c33a35dacb3e9a0) (thank you [Mikael Dúi Bolinder](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/18374/mikael-d%c3%bai-bolinder) for pointing out to that link):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, there is.

According to [people at Foursquare](https://foursquare.com/v/nyaung-u-airport/4d9c6db25c33a35dacb3e9a0) there's free and working Wi-Fi at most Myanmar airports now.